# Finding Primes in a List using Nested Loops

Tags: python, iteration, nested-loops

New to programming. I have the piece of code below and I'm stuck trying to figure out how to print out the list (odds) of primes in the given list. Please help with a way forward.

```
divisible = 0
dividers = []
odds = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17] #list to check for primes

for divider in range(2, dividers):
    for i in odds:
         if i % divider == 0:
           dividers.append(divider)
           divisible += 1

divisible == 0:
    print(odds)
```

Answer (score 0):

`for divider in range(2, dividers):` this expression is invalid. the type of `dividers` is `list` not `int`. What are you trying to do with these codes?

If you are trying to find which numbers of a given list are prime numbers, you should change your codes as below:

```
is_prime = lambda x: False if x < 2 else all(x % i != 0 for i in range(2, x))

random_numbers = [11, 18, 19, 22, 6, 3, 8]

prime_numbers = [i for i in random_numbers if is_prime(i)]

print(prime_numbers)
```

We should get an output like below:

```
[11, 19, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks you for the help.
I'm still new to coding and I'm trying to get an understanding of for loops. 
You did put up a valid point, the type of `dividers` is `list` not `int`, so how will I be able to change my code to iterate through the `list` of `dividers`?

Comment: The `dividers` list is an empty list. Therefore the `for` loop won't work as you wish. If you try to find which numbers are prime numbers from a given list, you can try to check the codes that I shared with you.

Comment: Okay, I get it. I thought python would read the `dividers` list as list of numbers `range(2, dividers)` since a prime number is a number divisible to 1 and itself (which is the `divider` in the `for divider in range(2, dividers):`